# html5 input date attribute selecting between two dates

Tags: html

I am using the html5 date attribute, as so:

```
<form>
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
</form>
```

It works great in that it allows you to select a date on a calendar. However, is it capable of selecting date ranges like the jQuery plugin does?

Comment: What are  you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RahulTripathi allow the user to select a date range, and have it appear as a comma separated list of two dates in the input field. Should i not use the input date attribute? It doesn't even seem like it is supported in firefox.

Comment: It appears the date type does not even work on firefox. I think I better stick to javascript for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can strictly do that using the HTML5 only. You need to use the Javascript as well to achieve what you are trying to do.

You can refer to  [Date Range Picker for Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

[image]

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am going to do. In fact, I added exactly that as a comment to the other answer, because the other answer is a hack.

Comment: @Donato:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<label for="start">Start date:</label>
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
   value="2020-07-22"
   min="2020-07-01" max="2020-07-31">
```

Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: This is not working for IOS device.